# SSRS IIF child visibility expression hiding parent as well

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Currently trying to implement SSRS 2014 as we now have an increased desire to have compatibility issues across all platforms resolved (Mac+Safari) which has been resolved. SSRS 2014 is rather elegant, however - I have run into an issue importing my Reporting solution and deploying.

9/10 Reports work, one does not - And I've found the issue to be a Child IIF expression to set visible to FALSE will ALSO hide the Parent. Parent is Question, and child is Question Data

The Parent Column is Question, the Child Column is Question Data - We have two sets of answers returned from the stored procedure.

> Q1) (Question) On display on entry? (QuestionData) Yes or No response
>
> > Q2) (Question) How? (QuestionData) varchar/str response.

The tablix (IIF visibility) is set to hide the anything apart from Yes/No, but leave the parent group, as the parent question is broken down into "How many Yes" "How many No" responses, and then "How?" If you see attached picture the flow is shown - (I've just blurred out the customer name + products)

[image: Example SSRS Grouping Issue]

I've got a custom function in the report code behind to count all responses as int for summing up. There are then drilldowns to seperate reports. If the 11 "Why not" was selected, the drilldown would show the text responses, rather than a SUM.

Any ideas how to **STOP** children hiding parent groups. This has clearly worked on previous versions of SSRS?

Thanks Kindly

Comment: This is really "Hacky" but have you tried setting the font colour to white instead?

Comment: I have thought about colours and bodging the report, however the "How" responses can be wordy, and if not hidden, how - could have 30+ unique responses and as such 30+ columns.

Comment: If you never want to show the worded answers can you not just use the inbuilt "count" function to see how many answers there were. I might be missing the point

Comment: Thats exactly what the report is doing. Counting how many responses against the How question there are. Unfortunately, I need to break down Yes/No responses and again use the same count function as demonstrated. Yes or No are the same as the How, Why Not responses, as such only these can be shown. Rather frustrating as this has always worked previously.